# How to escape {{ in AWS SSM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

We're using Atlantis & Terraform to set SSM values. One of the parameters contains raw `{{ ... }}` in the same syntax used by SSM for dynamic parameters.

AWS SSM refuses the value with:

> Error: creating SSM Parameter (/path/name): ValidationException: Parameter value: 'Something with {{ ... }}' failed to satisfy constraint: Parameter value can't nest another parameter. Do not use "{{}}" in the value.
> status code: 400, request id:

How can I format/escape the value to keep the raw `{{` and `}}`?

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not.